# How to access Azure IOT HUB data at AWS side

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-iot-hub, aws-iot, azure-data-share

I have a vendor that publishes the sensor data on Azure IOT HUB, we want to access this data from our application which is deployed on AWS. Is there any possibility we use some data share service OR a gateway service that helps to access the data from Azure IOT HUB to AWS side?

Comment: I have not done this to AWS, but to other hosted apps. I used the IoT Hub REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/)

Comment: It seems like this REST API is intended to use for managing the IOT HUB OR sending events from devices to HUB. In my case i needs to read the data only so not sure how it work for reading the IOT events over internet.

Comment: 0


If they publish data on HUB, then they choose a persistent data layer? Azure Storage container is a common endpoint. You might need to get a diagram of the event flow starting at the device.

Comment: @user565 are you interesting for a real-time telemetry data or historically telemetry data?

Comment: @Roman This would not be real-time.

Comment: @user565, in this case, your solution should be focused on the consuming of the Event Hub endpoint either an internal (built-in) endpoint or routing the telemetry data to the custom resource endpoint such as the Event Hub.

Answer (score 0):

As @user565 mentions, for near real-time, you can use directly the [IoT Hub compatible EventHub endpoint (Built-in endpoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin) or you can use [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c) to forward the messages to an Storage Account, Event Grid, or other Event Hub.

Using a full featured Event Hub allows you to use Kafka client applications / libraries to read from. Check Use [Azure Event Hubs from Apache Kafka Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/azure-event-hubs-kafka-overview)